# Out or Range Error and Friendly Criticism

Tags: c++, ascii

Hey Guys in this little encryption program I've made for some reason every time I run the code and enter the appropriate values I get this same std::out_of_range memory error when the program converts two strings to integers and adds them together:

```
number = stoi(szTempX)-stoi(qkey);
```

I've looked at all the other Stackoverflow pages about this error but when I apply the solutions to my code none of them seem to work. Also healthy criticism on how I wrote the code and how I code improve it will be much appreciated. Full code down below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void encryption(string text)
{
    char asciiChar;
    int asciiValue = 0;
    string key;
    string encoded;
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int random_integer = rand();
    cout << random_integer << endl;
    //Creates the key for the string.
    for (int i = 0; i < to_string(random_integer).length(); i++)
    {
        int asciiValue = (char)(to_string(random_integer)[i]);
        key = key + to_string(asciiValue);
        cout << asciiValue << endl;
    }
    int help = to_string(asciiValue).length();
    /*Function that converts the individual characters in the input
    string to AsciiValues and then puts them into the encoded data.*/
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        int asciiValue = char(text[i]) + random_integer;
        encoded = encoded + to_string(asciiValue) + ".";
    }
    cout << "Encrypted data: " << encoded << endl;
    cout << "Your key for this encoded data is " << key << endl;
}
void decryption(string text, string key)
{
    int asciiValues;
    int number;
    string qkey;
    string qmessage;
    string decoded;
    string szTempX;
    /*for (int i = 0; i < to_string(random_integer).length(); i++)
    {
        int asciiValue = (char)(to_string(random_integer)[i]);
        key = key + to_string(asciiValue);
        cout << asciiValue << endl;
    }*/
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i += 2)
    {
        std::string szTemp;
        szTemp += key[i];
        szTemp += key[i + 1];

        int nValue = std::stoi(szTemp);
        qkey += (char)nValue;
        // Use this for key: 5053574855
        // Use this for string: 25990.26023.26021.26012.26017.26010.


    }
    int wordlength = 0;
    wordlength = text.length();
    cout << text[0] << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < wordlength; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] != '.')
        {
        //This is where it triggers the breakpoint. 
            szTempX += text[i];
        }
        else
        {
            number = stoi(szTempX)-stoi(qkey);
            qmessage += (char)number;
        }
    }
    cout << "The decrypted string was " << qmessage << "." << endl;
}


int main()
{
    string answer;
    int question = 0;
    string vkey;
    ask:
    cout << "Would you like to:\nEncrypt Data[1]\nDecrypt Data[2]\nExit[3]" << endl;
    cin >> question;
    if (to_string(question) != "1"&&to_string(question) != "2"&&to_string(question) != "3")
    {
        goto ask;
    }
    else if (to_string(question) == "1")
    {
        while (answer.length() > 1000 || answer.length() < 1)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a string that has a length of 1 to 1000 characters. ";
            cin >> answer;
            cout << endl;
        }
        encryption(answer);
        cin >> answer;
        goto ask;
    }
    else if (to_string(question) == "2")
    {
        cout << "Please enter the string you would like decrypted. ";
        cin >> answer;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Now please enter the key for the string. ";
        cin >> vkey;
        cout << endl;
        decryption(answer, vkey);
        goto ask;
    }
    else if (to_string(question) == "3")
    {
        exit(0);
    }




    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i += 2)  => for (int i = 0; i+2 < key.length(); i += 2) , that expression grabbed my attention at a cursory glance

Comment: First, you will need a [mcve]. Then, __read__ what `std::out_of_range` means and where it may possibly originate.

Comment: Same memory error though I do appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: This is what a debugger is for. To tell you exactly where this exception gets thrown.

Comment: Sam I know and that is why above I specifically identify why this error is thrown but my question is why is it thrown.

Comment: From [stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) "If the value read is out of the range of representable values by an int, an out_of_range exception is thrown."  Now I've become google...

Comment: _"Also healthy criticism on how I wrote the code and how I code improve it will be much appreciated."_ You get that on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The number 5053574855 as the key does not fit in 32 bits. If that is by any chance the size of integers on your system it will cause this error.

Comment: @Heslacher I'm sure scop's comment considered just the code review part of the question. You know, because he quoted that ;-).

Comment: @Peter, yes, you're right.. :)

Comment: Thanks all for the help I think I've figured out went wrong via  Peter's comment about how the key does not fit 32 bits.